# Module title not getting from language file

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, language

Here is the module manifest file

```
<extension type="module" version="3.4" method="upgrade" client="site">
  <name>ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK</name>
  ...
  ....
  <description>ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK_DESCRIPTION</description>
  ...
  <files>
    ....
    <filename module="mod_quickwrk">mod_quickwrk.php</filename>
    ....
    <folder>language</folder>
  </files>

  <languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.mod_quickwrk.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.mod_quickwrk.sys.ini</language>
  </languages>
  .....
  ....
</extension>
```

**en-GB.mod_quickwrk.ini**

```
ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK = "Quick Work"
ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK_DESCRIPTION = "Quick work description"
....
....
```

**en-GB.mod_quickwrk.sys.ini**

```
ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK = "Quick Work"
ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK_DESCRIPTION = "Quick work description"
```

When I install the module, Joomla takes the module title as 'ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK' instead of 'Quick Work'

see the attached image.  The yellow color ones are not recognized by language files.  The green ones are ok.

[image]

I have some other language variables inside `en-GB.mod_quickwrk.ini` for module parameters which are loaded perfect.  The only problem is the title and description of the module.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is I need to keep the language files inside `en-GB` folder

```
<languages>
   <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_quickwrk.ini</language>
   <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_quickwrk.sys.ini</language>
 </languages>
```

:-)

Comment: LOL. I have a vague recollection something similar happened to me once.

Answer (score 2):

The proper method is like follows,

In your module's xml file it should have language file like follows:

```
 <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_latesttweets.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_latesttweets.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
```

and your fields like:

```
<field name="work" type="text" default="" label="ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK" description="ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK_DESCRIPTIONC" size="60"/>
```

Then module folder have these two files.

```
en-GB.mod_quickwrk.ini
en-GB.mod_quickwrk.sys.ini
```

Inside language file like below.

```
ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK = "Quick Work"
ABCD_MOD_QUICK_WRK_DESCRIPTION = "Quick work description"
```

Then Joomla will place this file in the proper language folder while you install the module.
Once you have installed the module and need to change the language labels. Should be change inside Joomla language folder file.

You can download a sample module from this [link](http://www.walkswithme.net/latest-tweets-joomla-module) and check the structure.

The issue look like your language file does not exists.

Hope its helps..

Comment: The OP is already doing this. All other parameters and description work fine, but it's just the title that appear to be wrong

Comment: @Ms. Nehal The language file loaded correctly. The problem is on the title which I highlighted in yellow... The only difference I could see yours and mine is I have the language files inside language folder where you have given it direct.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this recently with one of my modules in 3.6.

It didn't matter whether it was in a subfolder like 'en-GB' - what did matter was the name of the language folder itself. I'd originally misnamed it 'languages'; changing it to 'language' sorted it out.

Here's the working XML:

```
<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_mymod.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_mymod.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Very odd.